# Do cellphones damage male fertility?

Tags: mobile-phones, fertility

According to this [article](http://www.timesofisrael.com/cellphones-may-damage-male-fertility-israeli-study-finds/) wearing cellphones in the front pocket can cause men lose their fertility.

> Men using a cellular phone for more than one hour a day double the
> risk of their sperm count dropping to levels too low for procreation,
> according researchers from the Haifa Technion and the Carmel Medical
> Center.

I carry my smartphone in the front pocket all day long, not just one hour and this kind of information really disturb me. If phones really have these devastating effects on men, it should be prohibited and cellphone companies sued. It's like selling uranium or whatever poison. Why there isn't enough research done so this claim can be proved right or wrong for good?